# Findstr command and multi string search

Tags: batch-file, window

guys if I want like do findstr many time it just don't show the value of 2 & 3 in the line please correct me

```
>summary.txt (
  for %%F in (*chkpackage*) do findstr %1 "%%F" nul || echo %%F:N/A  && findstr %2 "%%F"  &findstr %3 "%%F"
)
```

I want to search on the string 2 and 3 too but why after I run this string 2 and 3 don't show

Did i use some syntax wrong?

like if in my resource text file have 
"

```
aaa 111 
bbb 222 
ccc 333 
DDD 444 
eee 555 
aaa 666
```

sting1 for aaa
sting2 for ccc
sting3 for eee

result in summary.txt would be like

```
filename.txt : aaa 111 : ccc 333 : eee 555 
filename.txt : aaa 666 : ccc 333 : eee 555
```

Thank you for any answer

Comment: Thank you for providing the expected output. But what is the corresponding input and what are the search terms you would be using to try to get the specified output?

Comment: input is like

abc.abc for string1 & 2 & 3

i just want to find the line that contain this 3 word and sum it 

then write to text file for later use in my excel( i used it with VBA)

Comment: What kind of logic are you trying to implement with the multiple FINDSTR calls? Is it `string1 AND string2 AND string3` or `string1 OR string2 OR string3` or something else, perhaps? It *seems* like ANDs all the way, but I'm not sure, even less so since you are saying it's not working as expected.

Comment: Oops, you seem to have answered my question while I was writing it. So it's ANDs, right? I.e. it should be the line(s) containing *all three* of the terms, correct?

Comment: Yes it AND :D i want to AND first

Comment: i think it's not ORs and ANDs ...  How do i put this T^T 

it like a new search for new string line but get the output sum up into 1 line

Comment: Oh, I see, seems clear now, thanks! My current answer isn't a solution then. I'm removing it and will try to think of something more helpful.

Comment: Your Solution is it like 

search for any lines that contain this 3 string right? am i understand correct

Comment: Yes, I thought at first that you wanted one line that contained all three arguments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24691/discussion-between-andriy-m-and-eathapeking)

Comment: This thread may be helpful: [Combining multiple .csv files into one .csv file line wise using a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985202/combining-multiple-csv-files-into-one-csv-file-line-wise-using-a-batch-file).

Comment: The idea behind using the solution posted on that question is to have three FINDSTR outputs, one per every search term, then join the results using a method similar to that in the answer.

Comment: yes seem like i have to use that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps is this what you want?

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*chkpackage*) do (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr %1 "%%F"') do (
      for /F "delims=" %%b in ('findstr %2 "%%F"') do (
         for /F "delims=" %%c in ('findstr %3 "%%F"') do (
            echo %%F : %%a : %%b : %%c
         )
      )
   )
)
```