# CMD or Powershell command to combine (merge) corresponding lines from two files

Tags: powershell, batch-file, join, cmd, merge

Is it possible using CMD and Powershell to combine 2 files into 1 file like this:

```
file1-line1 tab file2-line1
file1-line2 tab file2-line2
file1-line3 tab file2-line3
```

So it takes file 1 line 1 and the inserts a tab and then inserts file 2 line 1.  Then does this for all subsequent lines in each file?

Answer (score 6):

In PowerShell, and assuming both files have exactly the same number of lines:

```
$f1 = Get-Content file1
$f2 = Get-Content file2

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $f1.Length; ++$i) {
  $f1[$i] + "`t" + $f2[$i]
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. Two things worth noting: (a) This solution reads both files into memory as a whole (as arrays of lines), which may be problematic with large files. (b) The behavior is also reasonable if the line count differs: indexing beyond the bounds of an array in PowerShell yields `$null`; in the context of string concatenation, this is equivalent to the empty string, so once `file2` has run out of lines, you'll simply get nothing after the `"\`t"`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the simplest solution is to use a Windows port of the Linux `paste` utility (e.g. `paste.exe` from the [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)):

```
paste C:\path\to\file1.txt C:\path\to\file2.txt
```

From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?paste):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Write lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines from each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.

---

For a PowerShell(*ish*) solution, I'd use two [stream readers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
$sr1 = New-Object IO.StreamReader 'C:\path\to\file1.txt'
$sr2 = New-Object IO.StreamReader 'C:\path\to\file2.txt'

while ($sr1.Peek() -ge 0 -or $sr2.Peek() -ge 0) {
  if ($sr1.Peek() -ge 0) { $txt1 = $sr1.ReadLine() } else { $txt1 = '' }
  if ($sr2.Peek() -ge 0) { $txt2 = $sr2.ReadLine() } else { $txt2 = '' }

  "{0}`t{1}" -f $txt1, $txt2
}
```

This avoids having to read the two files entirely into memory before merging them, which bears the risk of memory exhaustion for large files.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Next line have a tab after the equal sign:
set "TAB=   "
Rem First file is read with FOR /F command
Rem Second file is read via Stdin
< file2.txt (for /F "delims=" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
   Rem Read next line from file2.txt
   set /P "line2="
   Rem Echo lines of both files separated by tab
   echo %%a%TAB%!line2!
))
```

Further details at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521799/combinining-multiple-text-files-into-one/14523100#14523100)

Answer (score 2):

A **generalized solution supporting *multiple* files**, building on [Ansgar Wiechers' great, memory-efficient `System.IO.StreamReader` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27237017/45375):

PowerShell's ability to invoke members (properties, methods) directly on a collection and have them automatically invoked on all items in the collection ([*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), v3+) allows for easy generalization:

```bash
# The input file paths.
$files = 'file1', 'file2', 'file3'

# Create stream-reader objects for all input files.
# Note: Convert-Path converts the $files elements to *full paths*, which is
#       necessary, because .NET's current dir. usually differs from PowerShell's.
$readers = [IO.StreamReader[]] (Convert-Path -LiteralPath $files)

# Keep reading while at least 1 file still has more lines.
while ($readers.EndOfStream -contains $false) {

  # Read the next line from each stream (file).
  # Streams that are already at EOF fortunately just return "".
  $lines = $readers.ReadLine()
  
  # Output the lines separated with tabs.
  $lines -join "`t"

}

# Close the stream readers.
$readers.Close()
```

---

`Get-MergedLines` (source code below; invoke with `-?` for help) wraps the functionality in a **function** that:

- accepts a **variable number of filenames** - both as an argument and via the pipeline
- uses a **configurable separator** to join the lines (defaults to a tab)
- allows **trimming trailing separator instances**

```bash
function Get-MergedLines() {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Merges lines from 2 or more files with a specifiable separator (default is tab).

.EXAMPLE
Get-MergedLines file1, file2 '<->'

.EXAMPLE
Get-ChildItem file? | Get-MergedLines
#>
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [string[]] $Path,

    [string] $Separator = "`t",

    [switch] $TrimTrailingSeparators
  )

  begin { $allPaths = @() }

  # Note: += to "grow" arrays is generally best avoided, given
  #       that a new array must be created every time; for *small*
  #       arrays, however, this method is convenient, without noticeably 
  #       impacting performance.
  process { $allPaths += $Path } 

  end {

    # Resolve all paths to full paths, which may include wildcard resolution.
    # Note: By using full paths, we needn't worry about .NET's current dir.
    #       potentially being different.
    $fullPaths = (Resolve-Path $allPaths).ProviderPath

    # Create stream-reader objects for all input files.
    $readers = [System.IO.StreamReader[]] $fullPaths

    # Keep reading while at least 1 file still has more lines.
    while ($readers.EndOfStream -contains $false) {

      # Read the next line from each stream (file).
      # Streams that are already at EOF fortunately just return "".
      $lines = $readers.ReadLine()
      
      # Join the lines.
      $mergedLine = $lines -join $Separator

      # Trim (remove) trailing separators, if requested.
      if ($TrimTrailingSeparators) {
        $mergedLine = $mergedLine -replace ('^(.*?)(?:' + [regex]::Escape($Separator) + ')+$'), '$1'
      }

      # Output the merged line.
      $mergedLine

    }

    # Close the stream readers.
    $readers.Close()

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Powershell solution:

```powershell
$file1 = Get-Content file1
$file2 = Get-Content file2
$outfile = "file3.txt"

for($i = 0; $i -lt $file1.length; $i++) {
  "$($file1[$i])`t$($file2[$i])" | out-file $outfile -Append 
}
```

Comment: Your command is missing `-InputObject` before the output string in the `out-file` call, because the string is otherwise implicitly treated as the `-Encoding` argument.
That said, unless you're concerned about memory (in which case the `System.IO.StreamReader` solution may be a better choice), `$(for($i = 0; $i -lt $file1.length; $i++) { "$($file1[$i])\`t$($file2[$i])" }) | Out-File $outfile
` is simpler and faster and also doesn't require you to ensure truncation of a preexisting output file beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of recent **locked** [duplicate] questions that link into this question like:

- [Merging two csvs into one with columns [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581048/merging-two-csvs-into-one-with-columns)
- [Merge 2 csv files in powershell [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097794/merge-2-csv-files-in-powershell)

were I do not agree with because they differ in a way that this question concerns text files and the other concern `csv` files. As a general rule, I would advice against manipulating files that represent objects (like `xml`, `json` and `csv`). Instead, I recommend to import these files (to objects), make the concerned changes and ConvertTo/Export the results back to a file.

One example where all the given general solutions in this issue will result in an incorrect output for these "duplicates" is where e.g. both `csv` files have a common column (property) name.
The general [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848821/1701026)) will join two objects list when the `-on` parameter is simply omitted. Therefor this solution will better fit the other (`csv`) "duplicate" questions. Take [Merge 2 csv files in powershell [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097794/merge-2-csv-files-in-powershell) from @Ender as an example:

```
$A = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
ID,Name
1,Peter
2,Dalas
'@

$B = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Class
Math
Physic
'@

$A | Join $B

ID Name  Class
-- ----  -----
1  Peter Math
2  Dalas Physic
```

In comparison with the "text" merge solutions given in this answer, the general `Join-Object` cmdlet is able to deal with different file lengths, and let you decide what to include (`LeftJoin`, `RightJoin` or `FullJoin`). Besides you have control over which columns you what to include (`$A | Join $B -Property ID, Name`) the order (`$A | Join $B -Property ID, Class, Name`) and a lot more which cannot be done which just concatenating text.

### Specific to this question:

As this specific question concerns text files rather then `csv` files, you will need to ad a header (property) name (e.g.`-Header File1`) while imparting the file and remove the header (`Select-Object -Skip 1`) when exporting the result:

```
$File1 = Import-Csv .\File1.txt -Header File1 
$File2 = Import-Csv .\File2.txt -Header File2
$File3 = $File1 | Join $File2
$File3 | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content .\File3.txt
```