# Merge/combine two lists line by line?

Tags: list, powershell, merge

I have two lists stored in variables: `$list1` and `$list2`, for example:

`$list1`:

```
a
b
c
d
```

`$list2`:

```
1
2
3
4
```

How do I merge them together line by line so that I end up with:

```
a1
b2
c3
d4
```

I have tried using array (@) but it just combines them one after the other, not line by line, example:

```bsh
$list1 = @(command)
$list1 += @($list2)
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27233249/1630171).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [Mark Wragg's helpful `for`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43681448/45375) and [Martin Brandl's helpful pipeline-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43681619/45375):

Combining `foreach` with `..`, the range operator allows for a concise solution that also performs well:

```
foreach ($i in 0..($list1.count-1)) { "$($list1[$i])$($list2[$i])" }
```

Even though an entire array of indices is constructed first - `0..($list1.count-1)` - this slightly outperforms the `for` solution with large input lists, and both `foreach` and `for` will be noticeably faster than the pipeline-based solution - see below.

Also note how string interpolation (variable references and subexpressions inside a single `"..."` string) are used to ensure that the result is always a *string*.

By contrast, if you use `+`, it is the type of the LHS that determines the output type, which can result in errors or unwanted output; e.g., `1 + 'a'` causes an error, because `1` is an integer and `'a'` cannot be converted to an integer.

---

#### Optional reading: performance considerations

- Generally, `foreach` and `for` solutions are noticeably faster than pipeline-based (`ForEach-Object` cmdlet-based) solutions.
- Pipelines are elegant and concise, but they are comparatively slow.

  - That shouldn't stop you from using them, but it's important to be aware that they *can* be a performance bottleneck.
  - Pipelines are *memory-efficient*, and for processing large collections that don't fit into memory as a whole they are always the right tool to use.
- PSv4 introduced the little-known `.ForEach()` *collection operator* (method), whose performance is in between that of `for` / `foreach` and the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*.

The following compares the relative performance with large lists (100,000 items); the absolute timing numbers will vary based on many factors, but they should give you a general sense:

```
# Define two large lists.
$list1 = 1..100000
$list2 = 1..100000

# Define the commands as script blocks:
$cmds = { foreach ($i in 0..($list1.count-1))  { "$($list1[$i])$($list2[$i])" } },
        { for ($i=0; $i -lt $list1.count; $i++) { "$($list1[$i])$($list2[$i])" } },
        { 0..($list1.count -1) | ForEach-Object { "$($list1[$_])$($list2[$_])" } },
        {        (0..($list1.count-1)).ForEach({ "$($list1[$_])$($list2[$_])" }) }


# Time each command.
$cmds | ForEach-Object { '{0:0.0}' -f (Measure-Command $_).TotalSeconds }
```

In a 2-core Windows 10 VM running PSv5.1 I get the following results after running the tests several times:

```
0.5  # foreach
0.7  # for
1.8  # ForEach-Object (pipeline)
1.2  # .ForEach() operator
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer pipelining, you can also do it in one line:

```
0 .. ($list1.count -1) | ForEach-Object { $list1[$_]+$list2[$_] }
```

Comment: Good one liner! However i only get a1 output (first line of each list) when running it? For example : $list1="a,b,c,d"
$list2="1,2,3,4"

$result=0 .. ($list1.count -1) | ForEach-Object { $list1[$_]+$list2[$_] }

echo $result.  This shows :  a1

Comment: You are initializing the lists wrong. your `$list1` is just a single string. Correct way is: `$list1 = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'`

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a `For` loop that uses iterates through the index of each object until it reaches the total (`.count`) of the first object:

```
$list1 = 'a','b','c','d'
$list2 = 1,2,3,4

For ($i=0; $i -lt $list1.count; $i++) {
    $list1[$i]+$list2[$i]
}
```

Output:

```
a1
b2
c3
d4
```

If you want the results to go to a variable, you could put (for example) `$list =` before the `For`.