# Is there a PowerShell equivalent of `paste` (i.e., horizontal file concatenation)?

Tags: powershell, join, transpose, file-manipulation

I want to *horizontally* concatenate a bunch of CSV files using PowerShell. (When considering possible "duplicate" questions", please not that "a bunch" is not "two".) What is the PowerShell equivalent of the Linux [paste](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) command?

Comment: There is no equivalent command. You'd want to import both files with Import-Csv, enumerate through them to build a new object for each record, and then write the result with Export-Csv. You could do the same with Get-Content, I suppose, but if you're going to bother with doing it yourself I can't imagine not wanting to benefit from the CSV parser in the general case.

Comment: As Bacon Bits notes, there's nothing built in. For files (only), direct use of .NET APIs offers a solution; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686729/45375) to the linked duplicate. iRon's proposal would certainly make for a nice addition to PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few months ago, I submitted a proposal for [including a `Join-Object` cmdlet to the standard PowerShell equipment `#14994`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14994).

Besides complexer joins based on a related property, the idea is to also be able to do a side-by-side join (by omiting the `-On` parameter).
Taken this [`Paste` command in Linux](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/paste-command-in-linux-with-examples/) as an example:

```
$State =
'Arunachal Pradesh',
'Assam',
'Andhra Pradesh',
'Bihar',
'Chhattisgrah'

$Capital =
'Itanagar',
'Dispur',
'Hyderabad',
'Patna',
'Raipur'
```

#### Installation

```
Install-Module -Name JoinModule
```

#### Creating a side-by-side *array*:

```
1..5 |Join $State |Join $Capital |% { "$_" }

1 Arunachal Pradesh Itanagar
2 Assam Dispur
3 Andhra Pradesh Hyderabad
4 Bihar Patna
5 Chhattisgrah Raipur
```

#### Creating a side-by-side *object*:

```
1..5 |Join $State |Join $Capital -Name Number, State, Capital

Number State             Capital
------ -----             -------
     1 Arunachal Pradesh Itanagar
     2 Assam             Dispur
     3 Andhra Pradesh    Hyderabad
     4 Bihar             Patna
     5 Chhattisgrah      Raipur
```

#### Concatenate ("Paste") two objects:

```
$List = $State |Join $Capital -Name State, Capital
$Id = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Id
A
B
C
D
E
'@

$Id |Join $List

Id State             Capital
-- -----             -------
A  Arunachal Pradesh Itanagar
B  Assam             Dispur
C  Andhra Pradesh    Hyderabad
D  Bihar             Patna
E  Chhattisgrah      Raipur
```

**References:**

- [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)
- [`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule)
- [Project Site](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object)
- see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)):

<sub>Please give a  if you support the proposal to [Add a Join-Object cmdlet to the standard PowerShell equipment (`#14994`)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14994)</sub>