# Powershell concatenate two files

Tags: powershell

I have a file 1.txt with content:

```
Package1
Package2
Package3
Package4
```

And another file 2.txt

```
Version
VersionExtend
Version
VersionExtend
```

I just want to concatenate these strings with a delimiter, which will be like below:

```
Package1:Version
Package2:VersionExtend
Package3:Version
Package4:VersionExtend
```

I tried

```
Get-Content 1.txt, 2.txt | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
```

But got this result:

```
Package1
Package2
Package3
Package4
Version
VersionExtend
Version
VersionExtend
```

Can you give me ideas on how to do it?

Comment: For some time now, I [purposed a `Join-Object`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14994) cmdlet to be put in the standard PowerShell equipment which the main goal to get an easier *PowerShell* syntax for joining object lists (including scalar list as in [a few other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68070763/1701026)). For the [purposed `Join-Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026) cmdlet, the command for this question would be something like `Get-Content .\FileA.txt |Join-Object (Get-Content .\FileB.txt) |ForEach-Object { $_ -Join ';' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're simply writing the content of the two files *one after the other* instead of processing *corresponding lines*.

**PowerShell has *no* built-in way for enumerating collections by positionally corresponding elements**,<sup>[1]</sup> but you can **use .NET APIs**:

```bash
# IMPORTANT:
# Since .NET's working dir. usually differs from PowerShell's, it
# is important to always use FULL PATHS when calling .NET methods.
# The calls to Convert-Path ensure that.

# Get enumerators for the lines of both files.
$fileA = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path 1.txt))
$fileB = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path 2.txt))

# Iterate over the files' lines in tandem, and write each pair
# to the output file.
& {
  while ($fileA.MoveNext(), $fileB.MoveNext() -contains $true) {
    '{0}:{1}' -f $fileA.Current, $fileB.Current
  }
} | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
```

- This solution is **memory-friendly**, as it reads the lines *lazily*, i.e., on demand, using the [`System.IO.File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadLines) method, obviating the need to read the files into memory *as a whole*.
- **If one of the files "runs out lines", an *empty string* is used in lieu of a value**.

  - If you want **to limit processing to only as many lines as the two files *have in common***, replace the `while` condition with:

    ```bash
    while ($fileA.MoveNext(), $fileB.MoveNext() -notcontains $false)
    ```
  - Alternatively, use a LINQ-based solution, as shown next.

---

**LINQ-based solutions:**

**Important**: The solutions below use the **[`System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip)** method, which **assumes that the the input collections have the *same* number of elements.** If they differ in element count, processing is invariably limited to as many elements as the *smaller* collection has, i.e. to how many elements they have *in common*.

- **Memory-friendly** too:

```bash
# Get enumerators for the lines of both files.
$fileA = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path 1.txt))
$fileB = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path 2.txt))

[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip(
  $fileA,
  $fileB,
  [Func[string, string, string]] { '{0}:{1}' -f $args[0], $args[1] }
) | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
```

- **Simpler** alternative that **reads both files *in full* first**:

```bash
[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip(
  (Get-Content -ReadCount 0 1.txt),
  (Get-Content -ReadCount 0 2.txt),
  [Func[object, object, string]] { '{0}:{1}' -f $args[0], $args[1] }
) | Set-Content joinedFile.txt
```

---

<sup>[1] A proposal to introduce such a feature, in the form of `foreach ($elementFromA, $elementFromB in $collectionA, $collectionB) { ... }`, was rejected, unfortunately - see [GitHub issue #14732](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14732).</sup>