# Insert new value to a CSV file into next column on corresponding row

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to read a csv file in powershell and for each item from the first column I am running a powershell command and I want the output to be added to the next column in the corresponding row.
The problem is that I don't know how to add the output from the command to the CSV in the corresponding row.
Ex:

To

A1,B1
A2,B2
A3,B3

add C1,C2,C3

as

A1,B1,C1
A2,B2,C2
A3,B3,C3

Comment: See [Is there a PowerShell equivalent of `paste` (i.e., horizontal file concatenation)? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68070763/1701026)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Select-Object *` to create new objects that are copies of the input, then add an additional property to each object by using a calculated property:

```
Import-Csv original.csv |Select-Object *,@{Name='NewColumnName';Expression={ Get-NewColumnValue }} |Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```