# Zip two select list?

Tags: powershell

I have the following object which needs to be converted to CSV file. The CSV file columns will contain all `data.attrs` and `data2.attrs`. `data` and `data2` are referenced by `data. Relations`.

```
$str = '{
    "data": [
        { "attrs": { "id": "A", "more": "A" }, 
          "relations": [{"id": "r11"}, {"id": "r12"}] },
        { "attrs": { "id": "B", "more": "B" }, 
          "relations": [{"id": "r21"}] }
    ],
    "data2": [
        {"id": "r11", "attrs": { "x": "11", "y": "1"}},
        {"id": "r12", "attrs": { "x": "12", "y": "2"}},
        {"id": "r21", "attrs": { "x": "21", "y": "1"}}
    ]}'
$json = $str | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The following code got all the `attrs` in `data2` for each row in `data`.

```
$json.data | 
% { 
    $_.relations.id | 
    % { 
        $json.data2 | ? id -eq $_ | select -ExpandProperty attrs # need to add data.attrs
    } 
} | 
ConvertTo-Csv
```

Output

```
"x","y"
"11","1"
"12","2"
"21","1"
```

How to add the columns from `data` in the list? There are many columns/fields in `data.attr`.

Expected

```
"id","more",....,"x","y"
"A","A",....,"11","1"
"A","A",....,"12","2"
"B","B",....,"21","1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` and `data2` properties have different structures. To align (and flatten) the `data` properties and the `data2` properties, you might do this:

```
$Data = $json.data.foreach{
    foreach ($relation in $_.relations) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            relation = $relation.id
            id = $_.attrs.id
            more = $_.attrs.more
        }
    }
}
$Data

relation id more
-------- -- ----
r11      A  A
r12      A  A
r21      B  B  



$data2 = $json.data2.foreach{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        id = $_.id
        x = $_.attrs.x
        y = $_.attrs.y
    }
}
$Data2

id  x  y
--  -  -
r11 11 1
r12 12 2
r21 21 1
```

To zip the object lists, you might use this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [Is there a PowerShell equivalent of `paste`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68070763/1701026)):

```
$data |Join $data2 -Name '',*2 |Format-Table

relation id id2 more x  y
-------- -- --- ---- -  -
r11      A  r11 A    11 1
r12      A  r12 A    12 2
r21      B  r21 B    21 1
```

For joining the objects, see your next question: [Join two objects - cannot add a member with the name "x" because a member with that name already exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74428711/1701026).