# How to loop through my text file and call the name of picture

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, nested-loops

I need to take all audio files from a directory, and export them along with one of multiple pictures listed in a text file.

It's working to take all the audio files one by one, but I cannot make it have a different picture for each video. I have same picture all the time.

1. I don't know how to make the loop working for the pictures files.
2. Will be nice if someone can tell me how I can group pictures in order to export as a slideshow.

Thank you.

In .txt file my pictures are like this :

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

And my code looks like this:

```
@echo off
set "sourcedir=E:\test slideshow imagini"  
set "outputdir=E:\test slideshow imagini\1" 
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (poze3.txt) do (
    echo %%A
    :: pictures names
     for %%F in (*.wav *.mp3) DO ffmpeg -loop 1 -i %%A -i "%%F" -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -vf scale=1920:1080 "%outputdir%\%%F.mp4" 
    POPD
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a trick to read the next line of a file with each run of the loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "sourcedir=E:\test slideshow imagini"  
set "outputdir=E:\test slideshow imagini\1" 
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
<"poze3.txt" (
    for %%F in (*.wav *.mp3) DO (
        set /p pic=
        ffmpeg -loop 1 -i !pic! -i "%%F" -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -vf scale=1920:1080 "%outputdir%\%%F.mp4" 
    )
)
```

(untested, but should work).

Btw: DO NOT use `::` as comment. Use `REM` instead.

I know, `::` is used often and behaves well outside of code blocks, but tends to hiccup when used within code blocks, leading to unexpected behaviour which is hard to troubleshoot.

I removed the `popd` in the loop. Repeatedly `popd`'s without matching `push`'s don't make sense. You do only one `pushd` before the loop, so the matching `popd` should be *after*  the loop, where you can omit it, as the script ends anyway.

Comment: One quick question please: How Can I use multiple .txt files in same time? This will help me for slideshow to have different input pictures and to merge them.

Comment: [up to eight files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32739680/2152082)