# Batch file line exchange by line number

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I've written a batch program that exchanges a line from a `.txt` file.
I have two `.txt` files:

The first one, `test1.txt` contains the record that looks like this:

```
1:hello
2:how
3:are
4:you
```

The second .txt file (`test2.txt`) contains a row with line number and looks like this:

```
3:good
```

I would like to replace the 3rd line from test1.txt with the one in text2.txt.
I have tried the following batch, but only get error messages:

```bat
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in (test2.txt) do (
    set lng=%%a
)   

for /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (test2.txt) do (
        set lnh=%%a
)   

set lineNumberExchange=%lng%
set lineNew=%lnh%

if exist beispiel.tmp del beispiel.tmp

set lineNr=0

for /f "delims=" %%A in (test1.txt) do (
    set /a lineNr+=1 >NUL
    if !lineNr!==%lineNumberExchange% ( 
        echo %lineNew%>>beispiel.tmp
    ) 
    else ( 
        echo %%A>>beispiel.tmp
    )
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you creating a line number variable?  You already have the line number in each file.  Why not look at the line number that is in test1.txt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521799/combinining-multiple-text-files-into-one/14523100#14523100

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `IF /?` to read the help file for the `IF` command.  You will see your error plain as day when you read the part about how to use `ELSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following code for this task:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "line_number=3"

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A IN ('type "test2.txt" ^| findstr /c:%line_number%') do (
    set "replace=%%A"
)

for /F "delims=" %%B IN ('type "test1.txt" ^& del "test1.txt"') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if not "!line:%line_number%=!" == "!line!" (
        (echo %line_number%:%replace%)>>"test1.txt"
    ) else (
        (echo !line!)>>"test1.txt"
    )
)
```

First, making a loop to find the replace word, and then replace with another loop.

Another way, you may want is to find the third line of both files or just assuming that `test2.txt` has only one line as mentioned in your question.

Assuming the above, the following code works:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "line_counter=0"
set "line_number=3"

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A IN (test2.txt) do (
    set "replace=%%A"
)

for /F "delims=" %%B IN ('type "test1.txt" ^& del "test1.txt"') do (
    set /a "line_counter+=1"
    set "line=%%B"
    if !line_counter! EQU %line_number% (
        (echo %line_number%:%replace%)>>"test1.txt"
    ) else (
        (echo !line!)>>"test1.txt"
    )
)
```

If your actual `test1.txt` file doesn't contain `n:` replace `(echo %line_number%:%replace%)>>"test1.txt"` with `(echo %replace%)>>"test1.txt"` in **all cases**.

If the same happens with the `test2.txt` file, replace `for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A IN (test2.txt) do (` with `for /F "delims=" %%A IN (test2.txt) do (` in **all cases**.

And assuming that the value stored in `replace` variable is in the third line, use:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "line_counter=0"
set "line_number=3"

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A IN (test2.txt) do (
    set /a "line_counter+=1"
    if !line_counter! EQU 3 (
        set "replace=%%A"
    )
)

set "line_counter=0"

for /F "delims=" %%B IN ('type "test1.txt" ^& del "test1.txt"') do (
    set /a "line_counter+=1"
    set "line=%%B"
    if !line_counter! EQU %line_number% (
        (echo %line_number%:%replace%)>>"test1.txt"
    ) else (
        (echo !line!)>>"test1.txt"
    )
)
```

Comment: I think the point is to dynamically generate the line number that needs to be replaced. You are hard coding the `3`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
selocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load original lines from test1.txt
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (test1.txt) do (
   set "line[%%a]=%%b"
   set "last=%%a"
)

rem Replace same-numbered lines from test2.txt
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (test2.txt) do set "line[%%a]=%%b"

rem Output final lines
(for /L %%i in (1,1,%last%) do echo %%i:!line[%%i]!) > test1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic version that allows the replacement file (`test2.txt`) to contain more than just one line, based on the following assumptions:

- lengths of lines of both input files do not exceed 1021 characters/bytes, including line number prefix;
- file to modify (`test1.txt`) contains less than 2<sup>31</sup> lines;
- line numbers of file to modify must be continuous and begin with one;
- line numbers of replacement file must be sorted in ascending order, no duplicates occur;

This is the code of the script, let us call it `replace-numbered-lines.bat`:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~f1" & rem // (file whose lines are to be replaced)
set "_REPL=%~f2" & rem // (file that contains replacement lines)
set "_RETF=%~f3" & rem // (return file)

rem /* Build temporary file path (the temporary file allows the return file to be
rem    the same as an input file): */
:LOOP_TEMP
for %%F in ("%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp") do set "TMPF=%%~fF"
if /I "%TMPF%"=="%_FILE%" goto :LOOP_TEMP
if /I "%TMPF%"=="%_RETF%" goto :LOOP_TEMP

rem // Determine number of lines of file to modify:
for /F %%C in ('^< "%_FILE%" find /C /V ""') do set "FCNT=%%C"

rem // Open both files for being read:
9< "%_FILE%" 8< "%_REPL%" > "%TMPF%" (
    rem // Initialise replacement line number:
    set /A "RNUM=0"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Loop through the lines of the file to modify:
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%FCNT%) do (
        rem // Read a line from the file to modify:
        <&9 (set "LINE=" & set /P LINE="")
        rem // Extract the line number:
        for /F "delims=:" %%N in ("!LINE!") do set /A "FNUM=%%N"
        rem /* Check whether buffer for line number of replacement file is defined;
        rem    if it is non-empty, there are still unread lines; if it is empty, the
        rem    end of the replacement file has already been reached: */
        if defined RNUM (
            rem /* Check whether line number from file to modify lies beyond the
            rem    buffered line of the of replacement file: */
            if !RNUM! lss !FNUM! (
                rem // Clear buffer for line number of replacement file:
                set "RNUM="
                rem // Attempt to read another line from the replacement file:
                <&8 (set "LNEW=" & set /P LNEW="")
                rem // Extract the line number (if the line is not empty):
                for /F "delims=:" %%N in ("!LNEW!") do set /A "RNUM=%%N"
            )
            rem /* Check whether the line number of the file to modify equals the
            rem    current (new or buffered) line number of the replacement file: */
            if !RNUM! equ !FNUM! (
                rem // Line numbers equal, so replace the current line:
                echo(!LNEW!
            ) else (
                rem // Line numbers do not equal, so keep current line:
                echo(!LINE!
            )
        ) else (
            rem // Keep current line since end of replacement file is reached:
            echo(!LINE!
        )
    )
    endlocal
)

rem // Return resulting file content:
if defined _RETF (
    rem // Move temporary file onto return file, if there is such:
    > nul move /Y "%TMPF%" "%_RETF%"
) else (
    rem // Display result on console and delete temporary file:
    type "%TMPF%"
    del "%TMPF%"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This reads the lines of each input files once only, so the performance should be quite well.

To apply it on your input files, call it by the following command line:

```cmd
replace-numbered-lines.bat test1.txt test2.txt
```

This displays the result in the console. To have it written to another file, use this:

```cmd
replace-numbered-lines.bat test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt
```

The output file may even be one of the input files:

```cmd
replace-numbered-lines.bat test1.txt test2.txt test1.txt
```

---

If the replacement file (`test2.txt`) could contain unsorted line numbers (without duplicates), the following approach could work (regard that all the other assumptions from above still apply):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~f1" & rem // (file whose lines are to be replaced)
set "_REPL=%~f2" & rem // (file that contains replacement lines)
set "_RETF=%~f3" & rem // (return file)

rem /* Build temporary file path (the temporary file allows the return file to be
rem    the same as an input file): */
:LOOP_TEMP
for %%F in ("%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp") do set "TMPF=%%~fF"
if /I "%TMPF%"=="%_FILE%" goto :LOOP_TEMP
if /I "%TMPF%"=="%_RETF%" goto :LOOP_TEMP

rem // Determine number of lines of file to modify:
for /F %%C in ('^< "%_FILE%" find /C /V ""') do set "FCNT=%%C"

rem // Open both files for being read:
< "%_FILE%" > "%TMPF%" (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Loop through the lines of the file to modify:
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%FCNT%) do (
        rem // Read a line from the file to modify:
        set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
        rem // Extract the line number:
        for /F "delims=:" %%N in ("!LINE!") do set /A "FNUM=%%N"
        rem /* Find line in replacement file with the same line number prefix as
        rem    the file to modify; if found, just return it; if not, then return
        rem    original line from file to modify: */
        2> nul findstr /B "!FNUM!:" "!_REPL!" || echo(!LINE!
    )
    endlocal
)

rem // Return resulting file content:
if defined _RETF (
    rem // Move temporary file onto return file, if there is such:
    > nul move /Y "%TMPF%" "%_RETF%"
) else (
    rem // Display result on console and delete temporary file:
    type "%TMPF%"
    del "%TMPF%"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This script is simpler and shorter, but the overall performance should be worse, because the replacement file is read once per line of the file to modify (`test1.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

IIUR the file `test2.txt` contains the line number to replace and the replacement text seperated by a colon.

I'd read the replacements into an array and check if one exists when iterating the file `text1.txt`

This way you could have multiple replacements (and also a longer text)

Given these sample files:

```
> type test?.txt

test1.txt

1:hello
2:how
3:are
4:you
5:

test2.txt

3:good are
5:at coding batches
```

this batch:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\02\07\SO_54576635.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: read in test2.txt into array Replace[#]=content 
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ("test2.txt") Do Set "Replace[%%A]=%%B"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("test1.txt") Do (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ("%%L") Do (
        If defined Replace[%%A] (
            Echo:%%A:!Replace[%%A]!
        ) else (
            Echo:%%L
        )
    )
)
```

yields this output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\02\07\SO_54576635.cmd
1:hello
2:how
3:good are
4:you
5:at coding batches
```

Comment: hello, I have tried your solution. In the echo, the output is displayed correctly, but nothing is written to the test1.txt?

Answer (score 0):

With `test1.txt` and `test2.txt` as in your question you could have this as `test.cmd`:

```bat
@(Set/P "_=")<"test2.txt"&Set/A #=_ 2>Nul
@(For /F "UseBackQTokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ("test1.txt") Do @If Not "%%A"=="%#%" (Echo(%%A:%%B)Else Echo(%_%)>"test3.txt"
```

This should output what you want to `test3.txt`.