# Multiple Text Files to a Single Output (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and I am struggling with a problem. I have 35 text files, each with different name, and I want to take all of these 35 text files and make them as one. Each file has 2 columns and almost 2000 rows.

The only thing I 've come up so far is to read the text files into Matlab using

```
for i=1:length(files)

    eval(['load ' files(i).name ' -ascii']);

end
```

and make the matrix manually using

```
final = horzcat(AA2,AA3,AA4,MN2,MN4....)
```

until I got to the last one.

Is there an easier way? In the future I will be using more than 100 text files so doing it manually is really time consuming!

Thank you :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Because when I do that, I can train the data using Neural Network Tool. Is there another way I can do that except Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this outside of MATLAB:

- [click here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8986/horizontal-file-concatenation) if you're on OSX/Linux
- [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031687/merge-2-txt-files-in-a-single-tab-delimited-file-in-batch) if you're on Windows

If you really want to stick to MATLAB,

```
A = [];
for ii = 1:length(files)

    % load new contents
    newA = load(files(ii).name, '-ascii');

    % concatenate horizontally
    A = [A newA];  %#ok

end

% save final output
save('outputFile.txt', 'A')
```

Comment: @Chrysovalando: Just remember you can mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking the big tick mark on the left of my answer. Happy to help!

Comment: Very nice as it completely avoids eval. If you have to deal with lots of files with a known number of rows and 2 columns you can consider preallocating A. Start with `A = zeros(numberOfRows,length(files)*2)` and assign like so: `A(:,2*ii-1:2*ii) = newA`.